# Django 1.6 to 1.11 Admin.py migration

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to port an old Django 1.6 admin.py code into Django 1.11 and for whatever reason, it is not working on 1.11. I am sending you the code below so some of you might give me some points on areas of the old code that will probably not work on Django 1.11. Thanks in advance for any hint.

---- admin.py -----

```
from django.contrib import admin
from webpad.models import Layout, Element, LayoutElement, Session, Click, DataGroup, DataElement, ReportTemplate, ReportBlock, Stream, Participant, Observer, Additional
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class FilteredUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.user = request.user
    obj.save()

  def queryset(self, request): 
    qs = super(FilteredUserAdmin, self).queryset(request) 
    return qs.filter(user=request.user)    

class ElementAdmin(FilteredUserAdmin):
  fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['name','group','connotation','color','add_to_video']}),
    ]

class AdditionalInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Additional
    can_delete = False

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (AdditionalInline, )

class ParticipantInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Participant
    extra = 0

class StreamAdmin(FilteredUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['stream_name','active']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ParticipantInline]

class LayoutElementInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(LayoutElementInlineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['element'].queryset = Element.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

class LayoutElementInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = LayoutElement
    extra = 0
    form = LayoutElementInlineForm
    def queryset(self, request):
      self.form.request = request

class LayoutAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(LayoutAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class LayoutAdmin(FilteredUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['layout_description','columns']}),
    ]
    inlines = [LayoutElementInline]
    form = LayoutAdminForm
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
      instances = formset.save(commit=False)
      for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
        obj.delete()
      for instance in instances:
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
      formset.save_m2m()
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
      ModelForm = super(LayoutAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
      class ModelFormMetaClass(ModelForm):
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
          kwargs['request'] = request
          return ModelForm(*args, **kwargs)
      return ModelFormMetaClass    

class ObserverInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ObserverInlineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['layout'].queryset = Layout.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    stream_list = Stream.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, active=True)
    self.fields['participant'].queryset = Participant.objects.filter(stream__in = stream_list)

class ObserverInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Observer
    extra = 0
    form = ObserverInlineForm
    def queryset(self, request):
      self.form.request = request

class ClickInline(admin.TabularInline):
  fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['element','observer','timestamp']}),
    ]
  model = Click
  extra = 0

class SessionAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(SessionAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    stream_list = Stream.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, active=True)
    self.fields['participant'].queryset = Participant.objects.filter(stream__in = stream_list)

class SessionAdmin(FilteredUserAdmin):
  fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['participant']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['session_start','session_finish'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
  form = SessionAdminForm
  inlines = [ObserverInline, ClickInline]
  def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    ModelForm = super(SessionAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    class ModelFormMetaClass(ModelForm):
      def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['request'] = request
        return ModelForm(*args, **kwargs)
    return ModelFormMetaClass

class DataElementInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DataElementInlineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['element'].queryset = Element.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

class DataElementInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = DataElement
    extra = 0
    form = DataElementInlineForm
    def queryset(self, request):
      self.form.request = request

class DataGroupAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(DataGroupAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class DataGroupAdmin(FilteredUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['visual_representation','group_description']}),
    ]
    inlines = [DataElementInline]
    form = DataGroupAdminForm
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
      instances = formset.save(commit=False)
      for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
        obj.delete()
      for instance in instances:
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
      formset.save_m2m()
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
      ModelForm = super(DataGroupAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
      class ModelFormMetaClass(ModelForm):
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
          kwargs['request'] = request
          return ModelForm(*args, **kwargs)
      return ModelFormMetaClass

class ReportBlockInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ReportBlockInlineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['data_group'].queryset = DataGroup.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

class ReportBlockInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ReportBlock
    extra = 0
    form = ReportBlockInlineForm
    def queryset(self, request):
      self.form.request = request

class ReportTemplateAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(ReportTemplateAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class ReportTemplateAdmin(FilteredUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['report_description']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ReportBlockInline]
    form = ReportTemplateAdminForm
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
      instances = formset.save(commit=False)
      for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
        obj.delete()
      for instance in instances:
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
      formset.save_m2m()
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
      ModelForm = super(ReportTemplateAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
      class ModelFormMetaClass(ModelForm):
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
          kwargs['request'] = request
          return ModelForm(*args, **kwargs)
      return ModelFormMetaClass

admin.site.site_header = "Feedback.Studio"
admin.site.site_title = "Feedback.Studio"

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)

admin.site.register(Element, ElementAdmin)
admin.site.register(Session, SessionAdmin)
admin.site.register(Stream, StreamAdmin)
admin.site.register(Layout, LayoutAdmin)

admin.site.register(DataGroup, DataGroupAdmin)
admin.site.register(ReportTemplate, ReportTemplateAdmin)
```

Comment: Please don't just throw us code to check. If you have multiple issues divide your code into several questions and tell us what you've tried, what is the exact error message, what line throws it, etc.

Comment: Upgrading 5 major versions straight away is never going to work, you should do so incrementally.

Comment: In any case, you need to tell us what actual problems you are having and what errors you get.

Comment: The first thing that works in 1.6 and doesn't in 1.11 is right at the top. The method def queryset(self, request): in class FilteredUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): is not called in 1.11.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be something simple. In my code above, there are a few methods like...

def queryset(self, request):

... which is fine in Django 1.6. But the correct override for Django 1.11 should be...

def get_queryset(self, request):